# Collecting password topologies from users in a secure way

Tags: security, passwords, password-protection

When a user registers itself on our site, we follow some well-defined security standards:

- generate a salt
- hash(salt + password)
- store the hashed password and the salt in the DB

Recently, a hot topic is "password topologies". For example, we should prevent users from generating a password like `Ullllldd` (Uppercase, 5 times lowercase, two digits) because they're so common and more easy to crack by brute force if the attacker just focuses on that topology. We would now like to generate information regarding the most common topologies used on our site. Obviously we cannot use the hashed password information inside our DB - we cannot recover the password information from that hash. We had the idea of keeping a topology table that gets filled whenever a new user registers. for example:

User "joe" registers with password "pass". we see if the topology "uuuu" already exists. If it doesn't, add it to the database table with count = 1. if it does, increase the count by 1. This is of course a bit risky: if our db gets compromised, our attacker suddenly knows our most common topologies!

So my question is: how to collect and store password topology information without creating a new security risk?

Comment: Password => Topology => Hash topology with fixed salt => send to separate storage mechanism => save there with encryption. This would mean both storage mechanisms would have to be breached.

Answer (score 0):

Your database should be a count of each used topology, without storing user ID attached the topology. On a second table, store which user IDs are represented in this database.

The trick comes from populating and updating the database. Collect and store information on password topologies whenever the user *changes* their password. Here, you'll be able to compute the old and new topology and decrement/increment the counts. If the user isn't represented to the database, add them, and simply add their new topology to the count.

Comment: That doesn't solve my security question: if the database is compromised, all known topologies are leaked to the hacker, which could then abuse this information.